# congruent to set of integers (mod)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

i do not understand what does this mean
can some one please help me understand this type of question:

Show that the following set of integers are congruent to `3 mod 7`.

```
{-38, 52, 66}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide each of the integers in your set by 7.  What is the remainder when doing so?  Another way to think of this is to write the fractions $\frac{-38}{7}, \frac{52}{7}, \frac{66}{7}$ as mixed numbers.  When we do this we see that the fractional part is $\frac{3}{7}$ for of these mixed numbers.  This shows that the numbers in our original list are congruent to 3 mod 7.

Comment: thank you this helped me so much – kunz 39 secs ago